# python CGI when run on localhost show all of code in file ? how to generate code

Tags: python

Code on localhost
[image]

location file C;/Appserv/www/pythonCGI.py

but config file httpd.conf when add .py on AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl ,and then restart apache
run on localhost show 500 internal server error